# Dynamic query in mongo with nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

```
dbo.collection('userinfo').find({_id:userdata.msisdn},{'_id':0,'subscriptions':1}).toArray(function(err,result){ //do something });
```

i want to replace the above query as below:

```
var myquery="dbo.collection('userinfo').find({_id:userdata.msisdn},{'_id':0,'subscriptions':1})";
myquery.toArray(function(){ //do something });
```

but second format is not working. please let me know how to use the dynamic queries in mongo. Thanks in advance

Comment: That simply is not going to work since `dbo` and `collection` and so on are actually objects and not "strings". Why do you think you actually want it in a string anyway as what part of the "string" are you expecting to change? MongoDB queries use "objects" for options and parameters, so what you likely really need is "dynamic manipulation of JavaScript objects", but your intentions in the question are currently really unclear.

Answer (score 0):

try this, it will work fine

```
dbo.collection('userinfo').find(
        { 
            _id : userdata.msisdn
        },
        {
            '_id':0,'subscriptions':1
        }).toArray(function(error ,results){
            debug(results)
        });
```

you can further make it dynamic by

```
let condition = {_id : userdata.msisdn}
let selection = {'_id':0,'subscriptions':1}
//other way of declaring    
// let selection= {}
//selection.subscriptions=1


dbo.collection('userinfo').find(condition,selection).toArray(function(error ,results){
                        debug(results)
                    });
```

Comment: That is am doing already. please read my question once again.

Comment: i have edited my answer , can you go through it once

Comment: Thanks for the reply. but i want that complete statement.